# Why I cannot see "In-app Products" under the application name?

Tags: android

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-list-setup

To create a product list for an application, follow these steps:

Log in to your publisher account.
In the All Android Market listings panel, under the application name, click In-app Products.

```
Why I cannot see the "In-app Products" under the applicaiton name?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "In-app Products" link yet because in-app purchase functionality has not been released to all developers yet. The documentation is just there as a preview so that you can start developing your app. It isn't possible to actually setup product lists yet, however. You'll have to wait until Google makes the functionality public.

Regarding not having linked AdSense yet, I have an Android Market publisher account in a country where that is not needed, just the link to Google Checkout which I have done, and I don't see the link yet either. So it probably isn't related to not linking AdSense yet. That was a good idea, though!

Comment: Link should be there now. In-app purchase opened up to developers to test :-)

Comment: What do you mean with "in-app purchase functionality has not been released to all developers yet" ? My developer account has been approved today, I updated a draft app, I have a `Google Checkout merchant account` and I have set the permission ` <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" /> ` . But I cannot set a price to my app and neither have `In-App Products` link there. So, how can I implement `in-app billing` then? So, do you mean that it is possible that this feature to be available a little bit later for new accounts?